# How to append existing array in existing collection in mongodb using java with new values

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a mongo collection like:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55cad746aed75601b4822cc9"),
    "entityId": "12",
    "entityType": "a",
    "nameIdentity": [{
        "fName": "abc",
        "lName": "def",
        "dob": "00",
        "address": "xyz"
    },

    ]
}
```

I am using `mongodb java 3.0` driver and trying to match and update. For eg: I am trying to match on `entityId` if it found then add the new `nameIdentity`.

Second time when I pass

```
{
    "fName": "123",
    "lName": "456",
    "dob": "00",
    "address": "789"
}
```

For my `entityId: 12` if it matches then my new collection should like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55cad746aed75601b4822cc9"),
    "entityId": "12",
    "entityType": "a",
    "nameIdentity": [{
    "fName": "abc",
    "lName": "def",
    "dob": "00",
    "address": "xyz"
    }, {
    "fName": "123",
    "lName": "456",
    "dob": "00",
    "address": "789"
    }]
}
```

I want to add it in the same matched object or collection. But its replacing the previous array and adding new like this:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55cad746aed75601b4822cc9"),
    "entityId": "12",
    "entityType": "a",
    "nameIdentity": [

    {
        "fName": "123",
        "lName": "456",
        "dob": "00",
        "address": "789"
    }
    ]
}
```

When entity id is matched I want everything to be added not updated. The code I tried is :

```
mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity").findOneAndUpdate(
    updateDocument, new Document("$set",entityDocument));
```

I tried with `$push` and `$set`. Its creating a new `nameIdentity` Array. But I want to add in same matched `nameIdentity` array. Any suggestions where am I going wrong ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should use [$push](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) like following:

```
db.collection.update({
    "entityId": "12"
}, {
    $push: {
    "nameIdentity": {
        "fName": "123",
        "lName": "456",
        "dob": "00",
        "address": "789"
    }
    }
})
```

Its equivalent query using mongo java driver is something like **(tested)** :

```
db.getCollection("entity").updateOne(new Document("entityId", "12"),
new Document("$push", new Document("nameIdentity", new Document("fName", "123").append("lName", "456")
    .append("dob", "00").append("address", "789"))));
```

If you want to update many documents then use [updateMany](http://docs.mongodb.org/getting-started/java/update/) instead of `updateOne` by passing required params.

Comment: If i am passing multiple arrays for eg name {}, address {},qualification{}, is there any shortcut way to update or i have to add all those manually in update query?

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli  What do you mean? you want to push multiple objects in `nameIdentity` with `entityId: 12`? if yes, create a list of such values and pass it to `$push`.

Comment: after i match entity id 12 ,i need to check fName,lName,address,dob  exists if it does then dont do anything else add like above. can u please help its urgent now

Comment: You should use `$exists` to check wheather field exist or not like I checked name here-  `db.getCollection("entity").updateOne(new Document("entityId", "12").append("nameIdentity.dob",new Document("$exists",false)),
                new Document("$push", new Document("nameIdentity", new Document("fName", "1223").append("lName", "2222222")
                .append("dob", "00").append("address", "789"))));`

Answer (score 3):

You basically want to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/) and add to the named array entry here. But for [`.findOneAndUpdate()`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/async/client/MongoCollection.html#findOneAndUpdate-org.bson.conversions.Bson-org.bson.conversions.Bson-com.mongodb.client.model.FindOneAndUpdateOptions-com.mongodb.async.SingleResultCallback-) you also need to set the [`ReturnDocument`](https://api.mongodb.org/java/current/com/mongodb/client/model/FindOneAndUpdateOptions.html#FindOneAndUpdateOptions--) type in order to receive the result.

Otherwise the "original" document is returned, just as it is for all drivers.

```
    Document entityDocument = new Document();
    entityDocument.append("fname","123");
    entityDocument.append("lname","456");
    entityDocument.append("dob","00");
    entityDocument.append("address","789")

    Document doc = mongoDatabase.getCollection("entity").findOneAndUpdate(
            new Document("entityId", 12),
            new Document("$push", new Document("nameIdentity", entityDocument)),
            new FindOneAndUpdateOptions().returnDocument(ReturnDocument.AFTER)
    );

    System.out.println(doc.toJson());
```

Comment: If i am passing multiple arrays for eg name {}, address {},qualification{}, is there any shortcut way to update or i have to add all those manually in update query?

Comment: @ShaikMujahidAli Well I actually showed you the "correct" syntax here and you chose not to accept. If you have new questions then post additional questions.